# Why is my program giving ambiguous reference to wstring error?

Tags: c++

Why is the following code is giving this error:

> reference to ‘wstring’ is ambiguous; i = wstring(ws);

I don't have any other function named `wstring` to cause the ambiguity.

```
int wstring(string &act)
{
    int i=0;
    vector<int> hash;

    while(act[i++]!='\0')
    if(act[i]=='#')
    {
        hash.push_back(i);
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int cases, i;
    string ws;

    cin>>cases;
    while(cases--)
    {
        getline(cin, ws);
        i = wstring(ws);
        cout<<i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your program have `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` somewhere that you're not showing? Because there's a `std::wstring` type defined in `<string>`

Comment: The error is in the part you have trimmed, voting to close.

Comment: Thanks...I had #include <string> and using namespace std; at the top...got what was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your code, do you have `using namespace std`?. Because if so, the call is ambiguous. You can fix it through:

```
i = ::wstring(ws);
```

Comment: that will pollute the global namespace and it is highly discouraged

Comment: @MarcoA. You mean the askers [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721), not this answer, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The answer I suppose should work

Answer (score 0):

`namespace std` has the same name as a typedef for `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` (i.e `std::wstring`). You have a name conflict because the compiler doesn't know if you meant `wstring(ws)` as a cast-expression to a `std::wstring` object or a function call. This is why, for one, `using namespace std` is not recommended, and why giving names to objects that have similar names in the global namesapces causes ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you also have at the top of your file

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

This is where your ambiguous call to wstring exists. [wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) is a type declared in string and the compiler can't tell if you mean the function wstring or if you want to create an object of type wstring and convert it to an int.